# Sharing internal storage using FileProvider

Tags: android, sharing, android-fileprovider

What I want is sharing files between my applications. I tried to use File Provider but It didn't work.

First In my plug app, I have set up a file provider:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mdl.test.plug">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ModuleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_module"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.mdl.test.plug.fileprovider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

my filepaths.xml:

```
 <paths>
    <files-path path="/" name="allfiles" />
</paths
```

And In an Core application, I tried to read test.txt:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.mdl.test.plug.fileprovider/allfiles/test.txt");
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        is = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (is != null) is.close(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
```

But It return a permission error:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord
```

What I want is Core can read files from Plug instead of Plug send files to Core. Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: You have not told where your test.txt file resides. Please tell full path. Further you should use getUriForFile() to setup the uri.

Answer (score 1):

> But It return a permission error

That is because the core app does not have rights to that `Uri`. You would have to be granted rights by the plugin app, by having the plugin app use some `Intent`-based IPC (`startActivity()`, `startService()`, `sendBroadcast()`, etc.), where you include the `Uri` in the "data" facet of the `Intent` and use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`.

> What I want is Core can read files from Plug instead of Plug send files to Core

That is difficult to do without also allowing any other app to read files from the plugin app.

If your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, you could create your own `ContentProvider` that is exported and defends itself with a custom permission. The core app would have a `<uses-permission>` element for that permission, and then it could make requests of that `ContentProvider` whenever it wants. If you give the custom permission an `android:protectionLevel` of `signature`, then your communications should be secure, though it would require the core app and the plugin app to be signed by the same signing key. However, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, custom permissions have some security issues.